# How to use a continuous color scale for thematic maps in the R package tmap?

Tags: r, gis, data-visualization, choropleth, tmap

When I make a choropleth with `tmap` where a continuous variable is mapped to fill color, `tmap` discretizes the variable and plots color by category. For example, this code

```
library(tmap)
data(World)
tm_shape(World) + tm_polygons(col="gdp_cap_est")
```

produces a map where countries are colored based on whether their GDP per capita is in the range $0-20,000, $20,000-40,000, etc. I would like a map where GDP/capita is mapped continuously to colors or shades of color, so that small differences in GDP entail small differences in color on the map. Does tmap have this capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `style` = `cont` or `order`.

```
library(tmap)
data(World)

# Map the value to a continuous gradient
tm_shape(World) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "gdp_cap_est",
              style = "cont")
```

[image]

```
# Map the order to a continuous gradient
tm_shape(World) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "gdp_cap_est",
              style = "order")
```

[image]